# Phrase for Someone Not Understanding the Value of Something

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there some phrase I can use for lamenting about someone possessing something very valuable yet not understanding or appreciating the value of this item? I feel like I've heard such a phrase before, but I can't think of it for the life of me.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this request that it was put on hold? You say to include information about how it will be used, but I don't know if that applies--I just wanted to know if a phrase that describes that situation exists because I felt like I had heard it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To cast pearls before swine" is a common (and Biblical, Matthew 7:6) aphorism for giving someone a valuable item of which they don't appreciate the significance or cost.